# JavaScript: how are functions and their scopes/lexical environments passed around?

Tags: javascript, function, scope, closures

I'm playing with closure and have no problem understanding how inner functions have access to outer lexical environments:

```
function outer() {
  var bar = 0;
  function inner() {
    console.log(bar);
  }
  inner();
}
outer();    // prints '0'
```

But what gets me is this:

```
function foo() {
  return function inner() {
    console.log(bar);
  }
}
function outer() {
  var bar = 0;
  var fakeInner= foo();    // not the same as "var fakeInner= function () { console.log(bar); }"
  fakeInner();
}
outer();    // ReferenceError: bar is not defined
```

Here I try to "define" an "inner function" `fakeInner` by assigning it to a function expression returned from an outside function.

I used to think that JavaScript creates the `fakeInner` inside with a "copy" of its code, something like: `var fakeInner= function () { console.log(bar); }`, which would then have access to `bar`, but this is not the case -- it appears when `fakeInner` is invoked, JavaScript traces back to its **definition**. Am I understanding this correctly? That is, function objects (either declarations or expressions) are mere references to their definition spots, and passing them do not change their lexical environments (hence inner functions have to be **defined** inside with explicit syntax)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, functions do only have access to their *own* lexical environment - from where they were defined. JavaScript does not have [dynamic scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Dynamic_scoping) where a function has any kind of access to the scope where it is called.

This happens by attaching the scope to the function object, it is a part of the closure.

Answer (score 1):

In this example,

```js
function outer() {
  var bar = 0;

  function inner() {
    console.log(bar);
  }
  inner();
}
outer();
```

scope of `bar` is `outer` function and will be available for all function defined in it.

```js
function foo() {
  return function inner() {
    console.log(bar);
  }
}

function outer() {
  var bar = 0;
  var fakeInner = foo(); // not the same as "var fakeInner= function () { console.log(bar); }"
  fakeInner();
}
outer();
```

In this example, again `bar` is accessible inside `outer` but `foo` is outside it. Hence reference error is thrown.

Also refer [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of inner functions is its own outer function.  Not the function it is being called from.